# CSS: backdrop-filter for button borders (potential solution?)

Tags: css

I am trying to create colored borders around buttons. The buttons themselves have a transparent but blured background (backdrop-filter). The borders however should be lighter/oversaturated depending on the image behind the the buttons. Essentially what I am trying to do is to apply seperate backdrop-filters to the borders.

[Example from MusicBee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkm5a.png)

What I've tried so far:

- just making the border a transparent white: looks good on flat colored backgrounds, but not on images
- playing around with hsla(): the saturation/lightness components are there, but I can only use one (hue-)color
- putting a div with slight overlap behind the buttons and using the filters on that: works with flat colored buttons, but I want mine to be transparent

EDIT:

I've found a "solution", but it's a rather ugly and restrictive one. Notice when you increase the thickness, the edges on the corners become really apparent. Is it possible to fix this?

https://codepen.io/schlossgeist/pen/YzVEear

(You may want to resize your window when viewing this example, so the button sits over a more colorful area, where the effect is more noticeable.)

I don't take credit for this concept, it has been done many times, not just in this exact same way.

CODE:

html

```
<div id=wrapper>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="links">Link
        <div class="linkT"></div>
        <div class="linkR"></div>
        <div class="linkB"></div>
        <div class="linkL"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am using a div for every edge, so I have full flexability.

css

```
:root {
    --thickness: 1.5px;
    --brightness: 2;
    --blur: 5px;
}


.linkT{
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;

    height: var(--thickness);
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background: transparent; 
    position: absolute;

    backdrop-filter: brightness(var(--brightness));
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
}

.linkR{
    border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;

    width: var(--thickness); 
    top: 0;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: transparent; 
    position: absolute;

    backdrop-filter: brightness(var(--brightness));
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
}

.linkB{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;

    height: var(--thickness); 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    left:  0;
    background: transparent; 
    position: absolute;

    backdrop-filter: brightness(var(--brightness));
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
}

.linkL{
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;

    width: var(--thickness);
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent; 
    position: absolute;

    backdrop-filter: brightness(var(--brightness));
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
}
```

Sadly, you can only use 2 filters on the border (one normal "filter" and one "backdrop-filter"). I found that blur and brightness are the best for my intended effect.

Can this method be improved/simplyfied in any way?